# Getting data from instagram

Tags: instagram

I have to collect data from Instagram posts (hashtags, geotag) to analyze the behavior of people in a certain area (city).
I searched a long time so far but did not find any sufficient for my task at the university. I am not that experienced in programming but I have knowledge in java, python and SQL.
Do you have any tips how to start?
the Instagram API with the sandbox mode is crap.
ty

Comment: i've not used the api but if it looks crap then your best choice is apis like yql or going headless

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a way to get data for people in a certain area (where area would be the input)?

Comment: Now even more concrete:
I have to count Instagram posts from Munich (it does not matter if its live data or not) and analyze how often a certain hashtag was used